# Powershell set combobox index from function

Tags: winforms, powershell

I want to modify the selection of a Windows form combobox from a function.

In the code below, the combobox is created in a function `New-ComboBox` and returned.

In a different function `Set-ComboBoxSelection`, I want to access this combobox and modify its selection. The function is able to read the selection from the combobox, but not to modify it.

Minimal example code:

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text ='Test combobox'

$main_form.Width = 300
$main_form.Height = 50
$main_form.AutoSize = $true

function New-ComboBox($cbstrings, $defaultIndex, $x, $y, $w){
    $combobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $combobox.Width = $w
    $combobox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
    $combobox.DropDownStyle = "DropDownList"
    $main_form.Controls.Add($combobox)

    Foreach ($strings in $cbstrings)
    { $combobox.Items.Add($strings); }  

    $combobox.SelectedIndex = $defaultIndex
    return $combobox
}


function Set-ComboBoxSelection(){

    Write-Host $combobox.SelectedIndex
    Write-Host $combobox.SelectedItem
    $combobox.SelectedIndex = 2
    $combobox.SelectedItem = $combobox.Items[2] 
}

$combobox = New-ComboBox "v1","v2","v3" 1 10 10 200
Set-ComboBoxSelection

$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

This will return:

```
The property 'SelectedIndex' cannot be found on this object.
 Verify that the property exists and can be set.

The property 'SelectedItem' cannot be found on this object.
Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

The values `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem` will however correctly return `2` and `v3` from `Set-ComboBoxSelection`.

Why do I have "read" access but not "write" access on this combobox?

For a TextBox, created within a function and returned, I'm able to set the `Text` value from within a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code comes from `Items.Add` which adds a few integer to the output so while you expect having a `ComboBox` as output, but the output is an array of objects.

To solve the problem you can suppress unwanted outputs:

```
$combobox.Items.Add($strings) | Out-Null
```

**More information**

In PowerShell, in addition to what you return explicitly using `return` statement, or using `Write-Out`, if you write a literal, a variable or a function call which returns an output or use write those values also will be added to the function output.

For example, `F2` in the following code will have two return values `true` and `1`. To be more precise, the return value will be and array of objects `object[]`, instead of `int`:

```
Function F1()
{
    return $true
}
Function F2()
{
    F1
    return 1
}
```

To prevent the problem, you can:

- `| Out-Null`: Use `| out-null` after functions to suppress their output, in above example `F1 | Out-Null`
- `[void]`: Cast the out-put to void, in above example `[void](F1)`
- `> $null`: Write output to null, in above example `F1 > $null`
- Capture the output in a variable, in above example `$null = F1`

Enough of the concepts, the When creating PowerShell function, you need to be careful about what is returned from the function. You need to prevent unwanted return values from functions, for example return value of `Items.Add` is also returned from function and as a result, instead of just returning a single `ComboBox`, you are returning an array of objects.

Comment: Would [void] in front of the call be the equivalent?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent. Or you can capture the output in a variable.

Comment: Cool! No problem :)